# Can I root a Superpad Flytouch 8?

Tags: rooting

I purchased a Superpad Flytouch 8 recently and now it hangs on the Android start-up page. I cannot access the menus for factory reset so I guess I need to get my head around "rooting".
The PC repair store says it can't be fixed but surely someone can help me prove them wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Android running to do a factory reset. Try following the steps in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-cZGkRcsiM) to reset your tablet.

Comment: Ive tried this solution many times, I cannot get the menu to come up. The closest I get is the android figure lying down with a red triangle.This was by holding "home" button and " power " button, but no menu appears!